# D3 Line with JSON Data, Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, svg

I have a Flask webserver that takes a dict of Python data and uses the jsonify function to return a JSON object when a GET is called on `/data`. The JSON object is not a nested list (see sample below) like most other examples on here.

I've been attempting to take that JSON data and pass it into my `d3.svg.line()` function, but it appears that something is wrong with the data I'm passing into it. My webpage renders the axes, but no line appears.

Inspecting the elements shows that the x and y axes are populated with my data, (`<path class="domain" d="M0,6V0H890V6"></path>`) but my `<path class="line"></path>` is empty.

I'm running a map function to convert my dates and values into their correct formats and returning them as an array. Running `console.log` on this function shows an output of a valid JSON object.

Can anybody help me out with where I'm going wrong here? Should I reformat my jsonified object to be a nested list instead and then populate my data object with `forEach`?

Below is my code and JSON sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body { font: 12px Arial; }

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>

<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var formatDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height,0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {return x(d.timeStamps); })
            .y(function(d) {return y(d.outTemps); });

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", 
                      "translate (" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.json("/data",function(error, data) {
            function type(d) {
            d.timeStamps = 
            d.timeStamps.map(function (time) {return formatDate(time) } );
            d.outTemps = d.outTemps.map(function (temp) {return parseFloat(temp)});
        };
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.timeStamps}));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.outTemps; }));


        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

        svg.append("path")  
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

        svg.append("g")     
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")     
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

        });



</script>
</body>


{
  "outTemps": [
    "79.7",
    "79.7",
    "79.8",
  ],
  "timeStamps": [
    "2016-09-20 19:15:07",
    "2016-09-20 19:10:07",
    "2016-09-20 19:05:11",
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is in a strange format for `d3`ing.  `d3` prefers arrays of objects where each property of the object represents an `x` or`y`.  So your data properly formatted should look something like this:

```
[{
  "timeStamps": "2016-09-20T23:15:07.000Z",
  "outTemps": 79.7
}, {
  "timeStamps": "2016-09-20T23:10:07.000Z",
  "outTemps": 79.7
}, {
  "timeStamps": "2016-09-20T23:05:11.000Z",
  "outTemps": 79.8
}]
```

Further, my guess is that your `type` function is an attempt at re-formatting the data but you aren't even calling it...

Finally, if you want to just re-format your data with JavaScript, it would look something like this:

```
  data = data.timeStamps.map(function(d, i) {
    return {
      timeStamps: formatDate(d),
      outTemps: parseFloat(data.outTemps[i])
    }
  });
```

With that correction, [here's your running code and plot](http://plnkr.co/edit/yLWhz6nHoNFFUw1L99Iv?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks so much! Is my data format not acceptable at all or was it more in my handling of it? Your function works just fine but I believe I can reformat my Flask function to return the correct values. Also, how far off base was my type() function, and where should I actually be calling it (for future reference).

Comment: Also, why do you call map on timestamps and not outTemps? data = data.timeStamps.map(function(d, i)

Comment: @prions, 1.) you could have called `type(data);`, this would have left the data in the **same structure** but coerced `timeStamps` to dates and `outTemps` to floats.  2.) IMHO, it is cleaner to have flask return the data correctly formatted.  3.) I could have `.map` either `timeStamps` or `outTemps`, as long as they were arrays of the same length it didn't matter.

Comment: Thanks again! I was able to reformat my data in Python by making a list of dicts. After that I just needed to run a data.Foreach anonymous function to parse my dates and temp values.